# Crosstab query to get number of records based on categories

Tags: sql, ms-access

Another question for today. MS Access.

given tables:
**FormsList**

```
FormID LocationID FormTypeID FormDate  
1 001 001 21.11.2012  
2 002 002 20.11.2012  
3 001 003 16.11.2012  
4 001 001 13.12.2012  
4 003 004 13.12.2012
```

...
**LocationsList**

```
LocationID LocationName  
001 FirstLocation  
002 SecondLocation  
003 ThirdLocation  
004 FourthLocation  
...
```

**FormTypes**

```
FormTypeID FormType  
001 "C"  
002 "R"  
003 "F"  
004 "X"  
...
```

I need a crosstab query, or something to get a table which has:

- Column 1 header: `LocationID`.
- Column 2,3,4 etc headers: "C","R","F","X".
- Column 1 - All LocationsID from **LocationsList**
- Column 2,3,4,5 etc - number of corresponding forms for each Location

Query/s should show the following result for above tables:

```
LocationID "C" "R" "F" "X"  
001 2 0 0 0  
002 0 1 0 0  
003 0 0 0 1  
004 0 0 0 0
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the following to transform the data:

```
TRANSFORM Count(FormsList.FormTypeID)
select LocationsList.LocationId
from (LocationsList
inner join FormsList
  on LocationsList.LocationId = FormsList.LocationId)
inner join FormTypes
  on FormsList.FormTypeId = FormTypes.FormTypeId
GROUP BY LocationsList.LocationId
PIVOT FormTypes.FormType
```

Edit, if you need all locations, then you will want to use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
TRANSFORM Count(FormsList.FormTypeID)
select LocationsList.LocationId
from (LocationsList
left join FormsList
  on LocationsList.LocationId = FormsList.LocationId)
left join FormTypes
  on FormsList.FormTypeId = FormTypes.FormTypeId
GROUP BY LocationsList.LocationId
PIVOT FormTypes.FormType
```

Comment: Genious... thanks :D  
For a bonus: I need all locations in first column, even if no forms are recorded for that location ( from Result table above case of 004)  
and all FormTypes in columns, even if no forms are recorded for that type ( from Result table above the case of "F").
Also, I want to see 0's ? **nz(Count(FormsList.FormTypeID),0)** ?

Comment: @AlinI If you want to see all locations, then you will use a `LEFT JOIN`, see my edit

Comment: OK, did that, and now I get a funny empty second column with header "<>".

Comment: on second thought, it's OK, I'll make another query with same number of columns as FormTypes number and use data from crosstab query (maybe it's ugly, but it's easy). Thanks bluefeet.
PS: if I use RIGHT JOIN I get all FormTypes like I want, but not all Locations. Now a funny second empty row :)